# Who sends the Holy Spirit? The Son or the Father?

Tags: john, luke, contradiction, pneumatology

> 7 But I tell you the truth: it is to your advantage that I am leaving; **for if I do not leave, the Helper will not come to you**; but if I go, **I will send Him to you**. (John 16:7 NASB)

vs.

> 26 But **the Helper, the Holy Spirit whom the Father will send** in My name, He will teach you all things, and remind you of all that I said to you. (John 14:26 NASB)

> 13 So if you, despite being evil, know how to give good gifts to your children, how much more will **your heavenly Father give the Holy Spirit** to those who ask Him?” (Luke 11:13 NASB)

Who sends the Holy Spirit? The Son or the Father?

Comment: J16:7 - this cannot relates to the HS -  HS has been here from the beginning & at Jesus birth and throughout - Jesus does not need to go away before the HS comes.

Answer (score 5):

I am unaware of anything in Scripture that even remotely forces one to choose between who sends the Holy Spirit, Father or Son!

It can surely be either one or both since Jesus declared that, "I and the Father are one" (John 10:30) which must mean, among other things, that they act in concert, concord, collaboration.

Thus, we find that:

- Jesus sends the Holt Spirit, Luke 24:49, John 15:26, 16:6; Thus, the Holy Spirit is also called, "The Spirit of Christ", Rom 8:9, Phil 1:19, 1 Peter 1:11
- the Father sends the Holy Spirit, Rev 5:6, John 14:26; Thus, the Holy Spirit is called the Spirit of God, Matt 3:16, 12:28, Rom 8:9, 14, 15:19, 1 Cor 2:11, 14, etc.
- the Holy Spirit is sent from heaven, 1 Peter 1:12.

This very idea of the Holy Spirit being BOTH the Spirit of Christ and the Father is testament to the closeness of these three great persons.  Recall that,

John 16:13, 14 - However, when **He** the Spirit of truth comes, **He** will guide you into all truth. For **He** will not speak on His own, but **He** will speak what **He** hears, and **He** will declare to you what is to come. **He** will glorify Me [Jesus] by taking from what is Mine [Jesus'] and disclosing it to you.

Comment: "This very idea of the Holy Spirit being BOTH the Spirit of Christ and the Father is testament to the closeness of these three great persons." That's two "persons". Not three. lol

Answer (score 5):

The answer is both! However, the Spirit comes specifically from the Father, even if it is the Son who is sending Him, as we can read here:

| John 15:26 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>26</sup>"But when the Helper comes, whom I shall send to you **from the Father**, the Spirit of truth who proceeds from the Father, He will testify of Me. <sub>(Holy Bible: New King James Version. Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

I would also like to point out that these passages are evidence against the claim that the Holy Spirit is co-equal with God, since Jesus is also recorded as saying this:

| John 13:16 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>16</sup>Most assuredly, I say to you, a servant is not greater than his master; **nor is he who is sent greater than he who sent him**. <sub>(Holy Bible: New King James Version. Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

Who is greater, the one sent or the one who sent him? Jesus said, "he who sent him". Who send the Holy Spirit? As you cited: both the Son and the Father. Hence, the Holy Spirit is not co-equal with them, but rather, the Father and Son are greater.

Now, although both the Son and Father send the Holy Spirit, does that mean that the Son is co-equal with the Father?

| John 14:28 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>28</sup>You have heard Me say to you, "I am going away and coming back to you." If you loved Me, you would rejoice because I said, "I am going to the Father," for **My Father is greater than I**. <sub>(Holy Bible: New King James Version. Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

Who is greater than Jesus? Jesus said, "My Father".

This also poses the question: Can the Son and Holy Spirit be God if there is anyone who is greater than them?

| Eph. 4:6 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>6</sup>one God and Father of all, who is **above all**, and through all, and in you all. <sub>(Holy Bible: New King James Version. Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

Who is above all? Paul said, "God". Hence, God has no equal, nor are there any greater than Him, which means that the Son and Holy Spirit are not God.

Rather, who is the one God who is above all? Paul said, "Father".

Comment: @RayButterworth "A servant is not greater than his master." Are you implying that the servant is equal with the master?

Comment: not (X > Y) implies X <= Y, so there is still a chance that X == Y

Comment: Carsonfel An excellent answer +1 wish it could be 100 Hope to see more answers like this based on the scriptures.

Comment: @carsonfel, I wasn't disagreeing with the idea that holy spirit is less than God, I was disputing only the false logic that "not greater than" must mean "less than".

Comment: @RayButterworth it's only false taken in isolation, but in the context of the passage, it indeed means "less than".

Comment: @RayButterworth, thanks for your thoughtful question. Agreeing with carsonfel, Jesus is not expressing strict boolean logic. We must pay attention to the Hebrew parallelism. The relationship between servant and master are equated to the one sent and the sender. It is plainly understood that the servant isn't simply not greater than the master but the master is obviously greater than the servant. The parallel truth is that the sent is not only not greater than the sender, but the clear truth expressed in parallelism is that the sender is superior to the sent.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting view of "the Father is greater than I" and the master greater than the servant in John 13:16.
In context, Jesus is comparing a human master and his slave/servant, not to Jesus Himself and His Father (God). Therefore, there is no superior vs inferior view.

In saying, "the Father is greater than I" Jesus as His Son is not speaking of superior vs inferior, rather He is speaking of rank. It is clear that a Father is "superior" in rank to His Son. Example: A general is superior to a private in rank, but not in nature nor essence; they are both male, human beings, and physical.

Also, Jesus has divested Himself of His omnipresence, omnipotence, omniscience in order to Incarnate Himself and die as a human being. That being the case, the Father who is Spirit is Omniscient, Omnipotent, Omnipresent, and only in that case is He "greater" than His physical Son.

Comment: Welcome, "Also, Jesus has divested Himself of His omnipresence, omnipotence, omniscience in order to Incarnate Himself", sadly not one word of that is biblical. -1

Answer (score 2):

Before answering whom it is who sends the Spirit, one must be careful to understand the relationship between the Father and the Son.

The Son is human in whom God dwells and through whom God speaks.

> To wit, that **God was in Christ**, reconciling the world unto
> himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed
> unto us the word of reconciliation. (2 Corinthians 5:19, KJV)
>
> For **I have not spoken of myself; but the Father which sent me, he
> gave me a commandment, what I should say, and what I should speak**.
> And I know that his commandment is life everlasting: whatsoever I
> speak therefore, even **as the Father said unto me, so I speak**.
> (John 12:49-50, KJV)
>
> Believest thou not that I am in the Father, and the Father in me?
> **the words that I speak unto you I speak not of myself: but the Father that dwelleth in me,** he doeth the works. . . . He that loveth me not keepeth not my sayings: and **the word which ye hear is not mine, but the Father's which sent me**. (John 14:10,24, KJV)

According to the Bible, God is in Christ, and God, who is in Christ, is the one from whom Christ's words originate.  Essentially, then, Jesus is not the one speaking, but the Father.

It follows that when Jesus said "I will send," he was speaking the Father's words; and when he said "the Father will send" he is identifying the source of those words.

**Conclusion**

The Father will send His spirit, in Jesus' name.  It is the Father who is God in Christ and speaking through him to promise us the Holy Spirit.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore, since He has been exalted at the right hand of God, and has received the promise of the Holy Spirit from the Father, He has poured out this which you both see and hear. Acts 2:33

Now Jesus is ascended and exalted to the Father, to sit at God's right hand, he can also send the spirit of God.

Jesus having represented the Father in every way without fault is now the spirit in himself.

> Now the Lord is the Spirit, and where the Spirit of the Lord is, there is freedom. 18 But we all, with unveiled faces, looking as in a mirror at the glory of the Lord, are being transformed into the same image from glory to glory, just as from the Lord, the Spirit.

It is the 'spirit' of God that empowers and guides the sheep God has chosen. Jesus and his humble and obedient heart is the essence of what God's spirit is. That's why we have many expressions like, the 'spirit of grace', the 'spirit of wisdom'. These are not separate entities, but represent the heart and will of God - as Jesus did and does as the firstborn of many brethren.

As the appointed heir, he has all that the Father has.

> in these last days he has spoken to us by his Son, whom he appointed the heir of all things, through whom also he created the ages. Heb 1:2

Either can 'send the spirit'.

Answer (score 0):

The Father promised, and it is the Son who gives and who baptizes.

He (the Spirit) is from the Father's bosom, but His Word (Jesus) does the giving/baptizing in the Spirit.

Ask Him (the Spirit) for yourself! "He will teach you ALL things..."

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by
Ashley Roberts' comment.

John 14:

> 26 But the **Helper**, the Holy Spirit whom the **Father will send** in **My name**, He will teach you all things, and remind you of all that I said to you.

Jesus was talking about the Paraclete. The Father would send in the name of the Son. He affirmed that 2 chapters later in
John 16:

> 7 But I tell you the truth: it is to your advantage that I am leaving; for if I do not leave, the **Helper** will not come to you; but if I go, **I will send** Him to you.

Sending the Helper was contingent on Jesus' going to the cross.

These two passages are strong evidence that Jesus' role is primary in the decision of sending the Helper.

On the other hand, Luke 11:

> 13 So if you, despite being evil, know how to give good gifts to your children, how much more will your heavenly **Father** give the **Holy Spirit** to those who ask Him?”

This passage is not specifically about the special role of the Holy Spirit, the Paraclete.

Who sends the Holy Spirit? The Son or the Father?

Both agree to send the Paraclete but Jesus' role is necessary and primary.

Comment: By Jesus saying that the Father will send the Spirit “in [his] name”, he is saying that the Father, at that point, is acting as a proxy for Jesus. This is how the contemporaneous hearer would have understood the phrase. 

E.g. [Knock at the door]; “State your name”;”My name is John, I come in the name of Peter Ben Joseph. You are invited to attend a wedding feast next month!” So the initiator of the sending is Jesus, in this case. Not to negate Dottard’s points in his answer above 

Comment: This is great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, the **milk**:

The Spirit of God is the Father's consciousness that He shares perfectly with His begotten Son, who then shares his spirit (consciousness) with us. In this way, the Spirit of God can only be accessed through the Son.

The longer more complete answer, the **meat**:

There is only one eternal Spirit and this would be the Holy Spirit of God. And by God, I'm referring to "the only true God" of Jesus Christ.

John 17:3

> And this is life eternal, that they might know thee the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent

Jesus tells the woman at the well that his God and Father is a Spirit.

John 4:23-24

> <sup>**23**</sup> But the hour cometh, and now is, when the true worshippers shall worship the Father in spirit and in truth: for the Father seeketh such to worship him. <sup>**24**</sup> God is a Spirit: and they that worship him must worship him in spirit and in truth.

Paul makes it clear that there is one Spirit.

Ephesians 4:4-6

> <sup>**4**</sup> There is one body, and one Spirit, even as ye are called in one hope of your calling; <sup>**5**</sup> One Lord, one faith, one baptism, <sup>**6**</sup> One God and Father of all, who is above all, and through all, and in you all.

Therefore, I will be continuing this explanation with the premise that the Holy Spirit of God **is** our Father's Spirit and not a completely other eternal spirit and/or person.

To use the parlance of the times, The Holy Spirit of God is the Father's consciousness.

Humans, born in the image of the Creator, also have a consciousness. This is our individualized soul/spirit. It's who each of us identifies as; what you are besides your flesh suit.
Modern man-made concepts concerning consciousness are still undeveloped and not fully defined. To put it simply your consciousness is your instantaneous thoughts and emotions.

The Father shares His Spirit (consciousness) fully and perfectly with the Son. That is how we say the Son is "**in**" the Father and vice-versa. They are **one**.

Our Master, the Son, likewise shares his holy spirit (his consciousness) with us. That is how we are **one** with the Father. We are in our Master who is perfectly **in** his God.

Acts 2:33

> Therefore being by the right hand of God exalted, and having received of the Father the promise of the holy spirit, he hath shed forth this, which ye now see and hear.

The holy spirit mentioned here is part of the glory promise Jesus received when he was exalted as we read above; a counterpart to his new spirit body. That is how we know this holy spirit is something different than the Spirit of God which is the Father's Spirit. He was immersed with the Father's Spirit during his baptism. Still one Spirit, however, because they share consciousness.

In the end, all of the children of Elohim will inherit a holy spirit, which will be one with the Spirit of the Father. At that time, God will be all in all. There is only one eternal consciousness and this is the Spirit of YHWH, the Eternal One.

Who is the Parakletos

John 14:26

> But the Parakletos, [G3875] this holy spirit, whom the Father will send in my name, he shall teach you all things, and bring all things to your remembrance, whatsoever I have said unto you.

John 15:26

> But when the Parakletos [G3875] is come, whom I will send unto you from the Father, even this spirit of truth, which proceedeth from the Father, he shall testify of me:

John 16:7

> Nevertheless I tell you the truth; It is expedient for you that I go away: for if I go not away, the Parakletos [G3875] will not come unto you; but if I depart, I will send him unto you.

The *parakletos* in chapter 14 is the Risen Son. I can say this with confidence because John, the same author of the verse in question, also wrote this verse:

1 John 2:1

> My little children, these things write I unto you, that ye sin not. And if any man sin, we have a Parakletos with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous:

It's important to note that in the 14th chapter of John, Jesus has not been glorified. He is speaking as the human Messiah, **not** the Risen Son in all his glory of his inheritance. The Risen Son inherits a spirit body and a spirit consciousness that he can now share just as his God and Father shared His Spirit (consciousness) perfectly with him.

The Risen Son is the Vine and we are the branches. The Spirit of God proceeds from the Father and moves through the Son to the rest of the children of God.

The Vine is the only pathway to the Father, and therefore, is the only doorway the Father uses to share with us His Spirit; upgrading our corrupted old spirit seed with the new incorruptible seed by way of the Risen Son who is the seed inside all of us who are born again.

In conclusion, the Father sends His Holy Spirit through the Son and in his name. You can't receive it any other way. Jesus is the way.

Answer (score 0):

John 14:26 NASB

> But the Helper, the Holy Spirit whom the Father will send in My name, He will teach you all things, and remind you of all that I said to you.

Jesus ordered man to render to Caesar as you would render to God.  This is why the Holy Spirit had to be sent so that man could understand why Jesus was crucified.  Taxation is a sin to God, it is worse than theft (they freed Barabbus but not Jesus).  The Holy Spirit is Lord God Almighty in heaven, Jesus is Lord God.  The Holy Spirit is sent by the Father at the request of the Son so that we would know the truth.  The Holy Spirit is the father of Christ (he who planted the seed).  Both Christ and Spirit are servants of the one true God.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.